# Limiting RAM usage for program executed through shell script

Tags: shell, memory, ram, limiting

I need to limit the memory(RAM) usage of a program to just 100mb.
I am executing a batch of them using a shell script and wanted to know how to do that.
I am compiling from source of my class and then storing the real run time using the time command.
Just wanted to know how to limit the memory usage of each to 100mb.

Comment: Linux - CentOS more specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play around with `ulimit -m`.  Type `help ulimit` and/or type `ulimit -a` to get a full list